# EF Core: Ignore property only on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have mapped an entity mapped to a database view (for querying data) and also to a table (for inserting, updating data).

To map an entity to the database view, I use this code ([from the EF 5.0 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#flexible-entity-mapping)):

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .ToTable("Blogs")
    .ToView("BlogsView");
```

In the database view, I have additional columns computed by the database (they are not present in a table). I need these additional columns on every select query, but I need to ignore them on save and update.

The `[NotMapped]` data annotation is not a solution because it ignores properties at all commands (select, update, etc.). When I omit the `[NotMapped]` data annotation, however, EF throws error on insert because EF tries to  insert values to columns which do not exist in the table.

The `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute is also not a solution because, in the SQL insert statement, EF produces a query which selects the columns from table, not from database view.

Is there any solution to achieve this with the Fluent API without separately mapping different entities to the view (with the additional columns) and the table (without the additional columns)?

Comment: You can't use `ToTable` and `ToView` on the same entity, that makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidG Well, the example is from the official EFC documentation.

Comment: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` works as expected: In INSERT and UPDATE queries the table is used and these columns are omitted. In SELECT queries the view is used and this columns are included.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to set both `BeforeSaveBehavior` (for insert) and `AfterSaveBehavior` (for update) of the entity property to `Ignore`.

Currently there is no fluent API for that, but you could use the metadata API, e.g.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(e => e.ViewProp1)
    .Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(e => e.ViewProp1)
    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

Comment: is it possibile not create column on table of ViewProp1? 
On ef core 7 it generate the column and with BeforeSaveBehavior , AfterSaveBehavior  setting not save value.

Comment: @GiovanniCaputo look for the `[NotMapped]` attribute in EF Core

Comment: If this works as I think it works, then this is the ideal solution to also exclude navigation properties from updating, something I was actually looking for and no other stackoverflow answer found regarding that topic. Does it work that way as well?

Comment: @CularBytes Unfortunately no. Navigation properties are... let say "special", and are not treated (or even accepted as "property" in fluent/model APIs) as primitive properties. Shortly, it definitely *does work* for primitive, and *does not* work for navigation properties.